# Switch to include column headers in bcp

Tags: sql, sql-server, export-to-csv, bcp

I don't see in the documentation how to include column headers with in my csv-type output file. I'm sure this is a duplicate, But I can't seem to find one that leads to my exact need.

Here's my command:

```
 bcp "select * from MYDB.dbo.MyTable" queryout "C:\outputfile.csv" -c -t"," -r"\n" -S ServerName -T -k -E
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A standard well known hack is to select the column names union all make them part of the query itself and export that, something like this......

```
bcp "SELECT 'ColName1','ColName2','ColName3' UNION ALL select ColName1,ColName2,ColName3 from MYDB.dbo.MyTable" queryout "C:\outputfile.csv" -c -t"," -r"\n" -S ServerName -T -k -E
```

Comment: thanks! Confirms what I've seen elsewhere. So Surprised this feature isn't inherent to bcp itself.

Comment: Without an order-by clause there is no guarantee the column name row will be the first row, and the data types must match or be able to implicit cast.

Answer (score 0):

@M.Ali solution works perfectly. You could also use the below to include the columns more dynamically:

```
DECLARE @ColumnHeader varchar(8000)
SELECT @ColumnHeader =  COALESCE(@ColumnHeader+',' ,'')+ ''''+column_name +'''' 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='tblA';
```